# CoreData: how to leave particular objects in context unsaved and save others?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios4

Prerequisites:
I have 2 methods in the network API:

- return list of entities (just basic info: name, id, etc.)
- return detailed info about entity

The requirement is to save only objects created by processing the second request (save to sqlite) and leave non-full objects without saving.
Also, the 'main' context should contain only full objects from 1st request, and any other 'temporary' context should contain all the others objects.

I've tried to create two instances of NSPersistentStoreCoordinator and use them for different types of contexts, but it seems that for one NSManagedObjectModel can exist only one coordinator (the pointer points to the same adress).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that exactly solves my problem is to create two 'forks' of core data stack:

- one with default config and mainContext
- the second (new instance of the same NSManagedObjectModel, new
  NSPersistentStore (inMemory) and new NSPersistenStoreCoordinator )

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then I think your best option is to only create a managed object once you're sure you want it to persist in Core Data storage.  You may need another layer of non-managed objects to contain data for the "non-full" entities

(This would be something like [Data Transfer Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) from Java EE programming.)

Comment: Thanks for good advice, I've already thought about this solution, but still wondering if it is possible on CoreData layer

Answer (score 0):

You can not save indiscriminately from within the same MOC.  Saving the MOC always saves everything in it.

So, you can use a separate MOC that is never saved, and then just "move" those objects to the main MOC when they are ready to be saved.